# How do i play an animation on a button press

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, button

Im making my first game but I am stuck. I am making the main menu. I want to make it that when I press the start game button an animation plays and it starts that game. I have no idea where to start. The button to start the game works and I have created the animation and that works but I don't know how to combine then.

I have tried to make the button play the animation play with 'animation.play' but that does not work.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

***Quoted Answer ***

First, open up your animator and create a new bool called "Run" or something you'll remember.
Next, write a script such as this, and place it on the character.

```
    public void PlayAnimation() {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Throw",true);
    }
```

Now, make a new UI button and click the "+" button to add a new OnClick function.

Next, drag your player into the GameObject prefab slot, click on the dropdown menu at the bottom, find your script's name, and go down to the function you made (For instance, it would be called PlayAnimation() in this case).

You can check [Unity answers](https://answers.unity.com)
and [Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/948812/ui-button-trigger-animation.html)

Comment: Also you can manually save your Animator component `private Anumator playAnimation;` and then populate it in `Awake()`: playAnimation = GetComponent<Animator>();`. And than you can play your animation with `playAnimation.Play("<name of your animation>"); Keep in mind that you should run this from script attached to your `GameObject` with `Animator` component, otherwise you should get your `Animator` component from other `gameObject` (the one you attached it to).

Comment: I suggest you update my answer and add these details if you want

Comment: Mmm, I've just remember more details about animation controller, so it'll be better to write a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you gonna have more animations consider implementing animator controller for your game.

In your Animations folder RMB->Create->Animator Controller. Next add an Idle animation for it (it's required by default), just create a new default animation, next add your desired animations (for example, FadeIn and so on). You'll get something as in the picture. Next attach your Animator Controller to the GameObject you want to animate.

[image]

For your scripts consider implementing it under GameManager or AnimationController, etc (it's a good practice). Get something like this:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToAnimate;

    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake() => animator = objectToAnimate.GetComponent<Animator>();

    public PlayAnimation() => animator.Play("FadeIn");
}
```

Don't forget to populate your `objectToAnimate` field and attach your `PlayAnimation()` function to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what Shrembo said, however, I wouldn't use a bool if you want to trigger the animation with a button - I'd use a trigger because you need to set a bool to false at one point.

So first you creator your animator controller by clicking in the project view > create > animator controller. Then you open that and drag in your animations. Now to trigger an animation you need to add a transition and on the said transition, you add the trigger parameter. 
(On the right side it will let you create that trigger)

Now in the code, you do the following:

```
public class AnimationMotor : MonoBehaviour 
{

public Button AnimationButton;

private Animator animator;

private void Start()
{

    AnimationButton.onClick.AddListener(() => 
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("MyTrigger");
    });
}
```

}